# Append additional parameters to the current URL with existing parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I wanted to append additional parameters to my URL. After searching in my search page I have this URL:
http://localhost:62265/result?search=sas

This is the link for the result page. wherein "sas" is the keyword searched.

Now what there will be additional filters in the same page. I would be filtering my current result further. Example: Location by country therefore the URL should look something like this.

http://localhost:62265/result?search=sas&country=Germany

Here is my current implementation so far.

SearchComponent.ts

```
//when a button is clicked it goes to this function.
search(){
  this.router.navigate(['/result'], { queryParams: { search: this.query } });
  //this is what I use to go to the result page.
}
```

AppModule.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //other paths
  { path: 'result', component: ResultComponent }
 ];
```

The question is how do I append the "&country=Germany" within the same component after adding additional features? I was fiddling with the router module's function and couldn't find one that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend your object with

```
{ search: this.query,
 country: [your country reference] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to build `queryParams` for the route. Add the param in the object based on your condition. For example, you can do it like this:

```
buildQueryParams() {
    const params: any = {};

    if(this.query) { Object.assign(params, {search: this.query}); }
    if(this.country) { Object.assign(params, {country: this.country}); }
    if(this.otherParam) { Object.assign(params, {otherParam: this.otherParams}); }

    return params;
}
```

then you can call that function in your `search()` method:

```
search(){
  this.router.navigate(['/result'], { queryParams: buildQueryParams() });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that it would not have to call the navigate function? It will simply just append the additional parameters.